# Consumir API mediante POST con Axios en Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, post, axios, postman

Estoy intentando consumir un servicio utilizando Nodejs y axios, este servicio depende de un Token para autenticarse y mi idea es utilizar el mismo Token para todos los envíos. Debido a esto necesito capturar cuando el token expira.

Una vez el Token expira, obtengo uno nuevo y es aquí el problema. Puedo hacer el consumo correctamente la primera vez, pero cuando el token expira y se obtiene uno nuevo, al hacer la misma solicitud , esta se queda pegada y no arroja ningún error conciso, solamente un error por tiempo de espera sin respuesta.

Esta es la funcion que utilizo para enviar los datos.

```
async function enviarDatos(data){
let resp;
let cabecera = Object.assign({
    'Authorization': token["token"],
}, data.getHeaders());
var config = {
method: 'post',
url: url+'wsCargaResultados',
headers: cabecera,
data : data
};

try{
    resp = await axios(config);
    resp = resp
    
}catch(err){
    //console.log(err)
    resp = await err.response
}
return resp
}
```

Al obtener un código 403, consulta un nuevo Token y lo asigna a la variable token.
Cuando genero el mismo escenario en postman, la solicitud pasa correctamente.

Comment: Hola!, pudiste solucionarlo? Intenta quitando el `await ` de la repuesta de error. `resp = err.response` y activa ese console.log para ver si la ejecución esta pasando por ahí.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu comentario. Finalmente cambie la estructura para usar el post de axios de esta forma resp = await axios.post(url+'wsCargaResultados',datos,config). Asi funciona sin problemas. Yo pienso que el error puede estar en el data.getHeaders(). pero aun no obtengo la respuesta a por que no funciona de la otra forma.